# Concatenate a column a df column in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concatenation

I have a df like this

```
col1    col2    col3                                                                                                                                                                                      
1       ab     file1                                                                                                                                                                                 
1       ab     file2                                                                                                                                                                                   
2       bd     file3                                                                                                                                                                                  
2       bd     file4                                                                                                                                                                                   
3       fe     file2
```

Now I need to concatenate col3 with ; delimiter.
The output shd be like

```
Col1  col2  col3
1     ab    file1;file2
2     bd    file3;file4
3     fe    file2
```

I have used concat_ws(";",collect_set(col3))

But sometimes in col3 I get file1,file2 and sometimes file2,file1.

How can I get the desired output.

Comment: Please format your question, it is difficult to undstand the column structures.

Comment: use `collect_list` not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort(col2,col3).groupBy(col2).agg(concat_ws(";",collect_set(col3)))
```

You need to sort the dataframe in the order that output is required.